# How to dynamically change launcher icon and name in Android?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, launcher-icon

My small app aims to dynamically change the app icon and name seen in the homescreen based on the value of JSON with on-prem key. The code below changes the app icon seen in the running apps tab and app name seen in the application UI. However it does not change the app icon and app name seen in the homescreen. How should I modify it to handle the issue? Thank you. Also there is full project if it helps: github.com/beyzaozbay/white-label

```
package com.example.whitelabelpreviousstep;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivityy extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String FLASK_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/get_data"; // loopback interface, i.e. localhost

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Allow insecure connections for testing purposes
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);

        // Initialize the Volley request queue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Create a JSON object to send to the Flask server
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("on-prem", "burak23"); // Change the value as needed
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create a JsonObjectRequest to send the JSON object to the Flask server
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, FLASK_URL, jsonBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Process the response on the main thread
                        handleResponse(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle error response on the main thread
                handleErrorResponse(error);
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the request queue
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private void handleResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            if (response.has("on-prem")) {
                String value = response.getString("on-prem");
                // Check the value received from the server and change the app icon, launcher icon, and app name accordingly
                if ("burak23".equals(value)) {
                    changeAppIconAndName(R.mipmap.imga, R.string.launcher_name_one, R.drawable.imga, "Burak 23");
                } else if ("burak24".equals(value)) {
                    changeAppIconAndName(R.mipmap.imgb, R.string.launcher_name_two, R.drawable.imgb, "Burak 24");
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("FLASK_RESPONSE", "Key 'on-prem' not found in JSON data");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error.networkResponse != null && error.networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
            Log.e("SSL_HANDSHAKE_ERROR", "SSL/TLS handshake failed: " + error.getMessage());
        } else {
            Log.e("VOLLEY_ERROR", error.toString());
        }
    }

    private void changeAppIconAndName(int launcherIconId, int appNameId, int homeIconId, String appName) {
        PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

        // Set the new launcher icon
        getApplicationInfo().icon = launcherIconId;

        // Set the new app name
        getApplicationInfo().labelRes = appNameId;
        setTitle(getString(appNameId));

        // Set the new task description with the app icon
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(homeIconId);
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(getString(appNameId), bitmap, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setTaskDescription(taskDescription);

        // Log a message to indicate that the app icon and name have been changed
        Log.d("FLASK_RESPONSE", "App icon and name changed successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: can I see you all your project , do you have GitHub ???

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. Here is the full version: https://github.com/beyzaozbay/white-label